# How to make a variation of a CSS style

Tags: css

I still new to CSS, and I was wondering if anyone here could point me in the right direction in regard to variations of styles.

If, for instance, I wanted to make a variation of the following style with a letter-spacing of 0.2em, how should I do that, and what should I put in the html tag?

```
p.text {
    font-size: 0.75em;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

What I've done so far is make a new style based on the existing style, but I assume there's a way of just varying the existing style.

Comment: you can define a new class that only includes the properties you want to change or add.

Comment: you can use css variables if you prefer

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML elements can have multiple classes, which can override styles.  For example:

```css
p.text {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

p.text2 {
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<p>This paragraph has no style rules applied.</p>
<p class="text">This paragraph has the "text" style rules applied.</p>
<p class="text text2">This paragraph has the "text" and "text2" style rules applied.</p>
```

It's common to make use of different classes, different [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), or even just the order of rules applied to over-ride styles.  In your browser's development tools, take a look at the DOM Explorer and select an element (at least in Chrome), and you can see the multiple "layers" of CSS rules applied and which ones override others.

Answer (score 1):

The way I'd personally approach this problem is as below, with explanatory comments in the code:

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  block-size: 100%;
}

body {
  font-size: 1rem;
  min-block-size: 100vh;
  padding-block: 1rem;
  padding-inline: 1.5rem;
}

/* everything above is just generic styling, and has no impact
   on the demo */

/* here we set the leading margin of the element to 0.5rem to
   visually separate each <p> from its preceding sibling;
   and also align the text to the start of the inline axis
   (basically to the left, in left-to-right languages, and to
   the right in right-to-left languages), see the "logical
   properties" link in the references: */
p {
  margin-block-start: 0.5rem;
  text-align: start;
}

/* here we set the letter-spacing of all <p> elements to be equal
   to the custom-property '--spacing', or if that's not set or is
   invalid to the initial value of the property: */
p {
  letter-spacing: var(--spacing, initial);
}

/* here we set the letter-spacing to 0.1rem via the custom-property: */
.text {
  --spacing: 0.1rem;
}

/* exactly as above, but to a larger (comedically so) value: */
.larger {
  --spacing: 0.5rem;
}

/* ...and to an even more ridiculously oversized spacing: */
.largest {
  --spacing: 0.8rem;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <!-- arbitrary class-names have been used in the HTML - 'text','larger', and 'largest' - to
       demonstrate the approach: -->
  <p>Qui quis possimus dicta corrupti optio eos veniam ea accusamus consequatur blanditiis mollitia iure suscipit illo beatae rerum nostrum sint excepturi cupiditate ea nostrum aut sit dolor corrupti doloribus sequi expedita eius in animi.</p>

  <p class="largest">Deserunt mollitia laudantium quae harum magni voluptatem magni iure quia dolorum expedita quo mollitia ipsum aliquid laboriosam at illum consequatur harum quos ab quibusdam excepturi.</p>

  <p>Dolore distinctio harum quasi rerum harum omnis labore explicabo voluptas facilis adipisci voluptates minus aliquam quo et lorem reprehenderit magni maiores omnis recusandae quibusdam adipisci repudiandae.</p>

  <p class="larger">Hic illo iusto eum distinctio autem distinctio in adipisicing explicabo eius magni neque maiores libero iure delectus dolore reprehenderit laudantium illo recusandae.</p>

  <p>Unde delectus nisi repudiandae repudiandae sint minus quas natus repellat alias vero amet sequi enim et ipsa ea dignissimos aperiam harum ipsam velit eum deleniti cupiditate quaerat cupiditate placeat aut consequuntur ratione in voluptatem debitis temporibus.</p>

  <p class="largest">Fuga fugiat eum magni nam veritatis earum ab odit voluptatibus consequuntur alias saepe dignissimos distinctio consectetur explicabo nihil eos libero reiciendis in consectetur nemo.</p>

  <p>Natus adipisci delectus excepturi qui quam ipsam voluptatum iure accusantium debitis harum ratione laborum harum quia repellat expedita sit necessitatibus dolore sequi.</p>

  <p class="larger">Possimus deleniti voluptatibus commodi id dolorum distinctio magni veritatis natus veritatis excepturi voluptatem alias at voluptatibus.</p>

  <p class="largest">Soluta quas quae ea porro lorem dignissimos enim magni laudantium voluptatem quisquam laudantium optio corrupti omnis.</p>

  <p>Dolores reprehenderit accusantium repellat neque molestiae harum nulla quo iure aliquam iusto temporibus at eius quae provident elit delectus illo deleniti saepe cupiditate rerum.</p>
</main>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/e37uxhr0/).

References:

- [`block-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/block-size).
- [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).
- [CSS Logical Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_logical_properties).
- [CSS Custom Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*).
- [`font-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size).
- [`letter-spacing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/letter-spacing).
- [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin).
- [`margin-block-start`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-block-start).
- [`min-block-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-block-size).
- [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding).
- [`padding-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-block).
- [`padding-inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-inline).
- [`text-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align).

Answer (score 0):

You can define a new class with only the properties you wish to change. Apply this new class alongside the original class directly in your HTML element.

**CSS:**

```
p.text {
    font-size: 0.75em;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.text-spacing {
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
}
```

**HTML with no spacing:**

```
<p class="text">This is some paragraph text with no letter-spacing.</p>
```

**HTML with spacing:**

```
<p class="text text-spacing">This is some paragraph text with increased letter-spacing.</p>
```

**Edit as per suggestion in comments:**

`BEM (Block, Element, Modifier)` is a popular methodology for naming and organizing CSS classes in a way that makes the styles more modular and easier to understand. In the BEM approach, you clearly define blocks, elements, and modifiers which can help maintain and scale the CSS of complex projects.

Applying **BEM** to your case, you can treat **text** as the block and **spacing** as a modifier of that block. The BEM naming convention uses double hyphens `(--)` to denote modifiers. Here's how you can apply it:

**CSS:**

```
/* Modifier: --spacing for the text block */
.text--spacing {
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<p class="text text--spacing">Your text here with modified letter-spacing.</p>
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but I would recommend doing **BEM** style here, since the `spacing` portion of the class is a modifier, the class would be `text--spacing`. Mainly the reason is `text-spacing` could potentially be a singular class on an element.

Comment: You're absolutely right, and I appreciate your suggestion. I'll edit my answer to include this.